# Retrieve property from all instances of one class in Matlab, write value to file

Tags: matlab, oop

I would like to automatically retrieve certain properties from all instances of the same class in my workspace.

Ex.: I have a class C1, with instances a, b, c, d.
     Each of these have a certain property called x. I would like to retrieve all the x's.
How do I go about this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to structure your code so that you keep `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in one array?

Comment: I would like to use a way which does not influence how my objects are created, like using 'whos' to find all instances of my class and then go on from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility. Let's say that I want to find all the doubles in the workspace. I could do something like this

```
>> x = 12.3;
>> y = 45.6;
>> z = '789';
```

Get a list of all variables in the workspace

```
>> vars = whos();
```

Figure out which ones are doubles

```
>> location = strcmp('double',{vars.class});
```

Get their names

```
>> names = {vars(location).name};
>> names
names = 
    'x'    'y'
```

If you now wanted to get an array of some property x (say I want to get the cosine of each double) you could do something like this

```
>> N = length(names);
>> arr = NaN(1,N);
>> for n = 1:N
     obj    = eval(names{n}); # dubious use of 'eval'
     arr(n) = cos(obj);       # assign the relevant property to an array
   end
```

Now you have

```
>> arr
arr =
    0.9647   -0.0469
```

---

Here's an example using a custom object. First, I put this code in the file *DProtein.m*

```
classdef DProtein
    properties
        x;
        y;
    end
    methods
        function self = DProtein(x, y)
            self.x = x;
            self.y = y;
        end
    end
end
```

Now I create a couple of objects

```
>> a = DProtein(1, 'foo'); # a.x = 1
>> b = DProtein(2, 'bar'); # b.x = 2
```

I find all of the objects of the correct class in the workspace as before

```
>> vars = whos();
>> location = strcmp('DProtein', {vars.class});
>> names = {vars(location).name};
```

Now a loop collects an array of every object

```
>> for n = 1:length(names)
       objects(n) = eval(names{n}); # N.B. important that 'objects' does not
                                    # exist in the workspace before this line!
   end
```

And you can collect all the properties like this

```
>> [objects.x]
ans =
    1    2
```

Comment: But how would I reference different properties? My classes don't just have one property, but many. How can I specify which one to use? I don't really get the use of 'eval' here...

Edit: the eval tries to convert the object to double, which is not very useful if it is about a custom made class.

Comment: @lhcgeneva You can change the `eval` to be eval([names{n}, ".x"]) to only get the `x` property. Otherwise you might be able to leave the `eval` as is and change `cos(obj)` to `obj.x`. `eval` is used here to get hold of the instance (an object) you want based only on the object name (a string).

Comment: I just tried this, the referencing doesn't work, I get an error:
The following error occurred converting from DProtein to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from DProtein is not possible.
DProtein is my class.

Comment: What is the class of the property you are trying to get hold of? Also, what code are you trying to run?

Comment: @Chris, Dan In fact I would like to use sth like Dan proposed, but automated. Like creating an array with all the objects that already exist. Then I could easily retrieve the properties.